# Liquid simulation - wrong flowing direction

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, settings

I try to make a liquid simulation but find a problem that can not fix.

[image]

As the picture shows, the liquid flow in the wrong direction and I want it to be a straight line

Here is the setting. please give me some suggestions

[image]

Comment: You scene gravity seems correct: is your *Gravity* in the *Field Weights* also a positive number?

Comment: You may want to include a reduced size version of your liquid Domain and Effector and Flows objects only.  Is the liquid flowing out of a pipe (as it appears in the first image)?

Comment: Do you have any force fields in the scene?

Comment: It's Viscosity in the Domain that you'll need to focus on.  If you disable it doesn't curl around like soft-serve ice cream and you should keep it disabled if you want something like water.   Otherwise lower this from your already low value of 0.05 (try 0.02) if you want to have a viscus liquid like syrup.  And you might want to adjust the *particle radius* along with.

Comment: So it is no solution to fix it if I must use Viscosity?